# ngx-joyride not showing when click on button

Tags: angular9

I have implemented **ngx-joyride** for the demo purpose of my website.

But it is not showing anything when clicking on the button (joyride is button).

I am attaching the screenshot of my angular 9 browser console and webpage so that you can get better idea.

Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.[image: Error and browser dom]

```js
//Angular 9 code 
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
  AfterViewInit,
} from "@angular/core";
import { JoyrideService } from "ngx-joyride";

@Component({
  selector: "app-temporary",
  templateUrl: "./temporary.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./temporary.component.scss"],
})
export class TemporaryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private joyride: JoyrideService) {}

  @ViewChild("ele1", { static: false }) ele1: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("ele2", { static: false }) ele2: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("1", this.ele1);
    console.log("2", this.ele2);
  }

  //ngx-joyride-tour
  onClick() {
    // alert("coming here 1");

    console.log("joyrideService", this.joyride);
    this.joyride
      .startTour({ steps: ["ONE", "TWO"], logsEnabled: true })
      .subscribe(
        (step) => {
          console.log("coming step section");
          console.log(step);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("coming in error section");
        },
        () => {
          console.log("tour finished");
        }
      );
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="onClick()">joyride</button>
    <div joyrideStep="ONE" title="Page Title" text="Main title!" #ele1>Text</div>
    <div joyrideStep="TWO" title="Page Title" text="Main title!" #ele2>Div content</div>
</div>
<h1>Temporary PAge</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were mistaken by us we have not added a joyride module with `forChild()` in lazy loaded modules.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In your root AppModule, import JoyrideModule using forRoot() method:

```
 import { JoyrideModule } from 'ngx-joyride';
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        JoyrideModule.forRoot()
      ],
      ...
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**2**. In your child module, import JoyrideModule using forChild() method:

```
import { JoyrideModule } from 'ngx-joyride';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    JoyrideModule.forChild()
  ],
  ...
})
export class YourChildModule { }
```